# Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer um site com design responsivo

Tags: html, css

Bom, eu sempre que tento fazer algum site, em html e css (visto que não sou muito bom de design), o site fica perfeito para mim, todo direito etc...

Mas quando vou ver em outro computador, ou seja com resolução diferente, fica completamente destrocido.

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer um site em design responsivo, visto que eu já utilizo a % e mesmo assim, continua ficando todo destrocido.

Podiam me dar alguns exemplos de tecnicas em html e css?

Obrigado.

Comment: Bootstrap é bem interessante. Já usou?

Comment: Já pensou em comprar layouts prontos? Acho a melhor opção pra quem não sabe sobre interface web. É muito mais fácil editar um layout responsivo pra ficar do seu jeito do que fazer do zero.

Comment: Eu uso o bootstrap, me facilita muito neste ponto.
Mas se quiseres aprender mais estude sobre Media Queries CSS.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá, Gonçalo! Marquei a pergunta como pendente porque ela não se enquadra muito bem na objetividade que a comunidade busca para o site, afinal não existe uma melhor forma de fazer design responsivo, depende muito da situação e do projeto. Tanto que as 3 respostas que foram colocadas até o momento apenas opiniões e sugerem algumas soluções muito limitadas, mas nenhum atende - e nem poderia atender - a uma pergunta tão abrangente como essa. No entanto, fique à vontade se quiser fazer uma pergunta mais específica ou mesmo editar esta para tentar torná-la mais objetiva. Abraço!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma dica para começar a fazer designs responsivos e padronizados é usar o framework [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) .

Eles possuem um template inicial bem básico e uma ótima documentação para se aprender. Comece [aqui](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html)

O site **Tableless** também possui um ótimo tutorial de design responsivo. Acesse [aqui](http://tableless.com.br/design-responsivo-na-pratica-do-rascunho-ao-digita/)

Boa sorte!

Comment: Ta apoiado, uso faz muito tempo e é ótimo.

Comment: Leonardo podes juntar aqui exemplos? Senão como está a resposta aponta para links em Inglês e perde o sentido de ser colocado aqui no SOpt. Obrigado!

Comment: Olá Leonardo, os links são interessantes, mas só uma dica: respostas que se baseiam somente em links não são geralmente bem aceitas - embora nesse caso específico você tenha recebido alguns votos a favor. Se considerar só o texto da resposta, um usuário que não conheça o framework ou o site Tableless ficaria sem nenhuma pista sobre o que cada coisa faz e o que uma coisa tem a ver com a outra. Abraço!

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback. Melhorarei as respostas e usarei os links somente como referências. Obrigado novamente

Answer (score 2):

Desenvolver uma interface responsiva não é uma tarefa assim tão simples, pois em um layout responsivo sempre será necessário além de utilizar elementos com tamanhos relativos, ocultar elementos, diminuir ou aumentar tamanhos de fontes, imagens e etc. Para isso também será necessário conhecer regras [CSS3 @media Rule.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Veja alguns exemplos:

```css
div{
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
h1{
  color:blue;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    h1 {
        color: red;
        font-size:56px;
    }
    
   
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  ul {
    display:none;
    }
   button{
      display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>REDIMENSIONE O TAMANHO DA TELA</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
  </ul>
  <button>AÇÃO</button>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1zjbu0j/2/)**

Para criar seu próprio layout responsivo você terá bastante trabalho para adaptá-lo a todas as dimensões possíveis de telas, porém para facilitar este desenvolvimento existem frameworks como: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/), [Google Material Design](https://material.google.com/) e entre outros, que já possuem classes e elementos específicos.